# What's the different between "kind of" and "sort of" in English

Tags: american-english

What's the different between "kind of" and "sort of" in American informal English?

Comment: The difference is that in AmE Jack Nicholson in [*The Missouri Breaks*](http://www.flixster.com/movie/the-missouri-breaks/) can pun that he has a ***sawed-off** shotgun* because he's a ***sort of** sportsman*. Which doesn't work in BrE because we have ***sawn-off** shotguns*. Otherwise, they're sort of interchangeable.

Comment: They're kinda sorta the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, no difference.  They are equivalent.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: seems like the person who posed said question disagrees...